# The Grinder: the console does not see the agent

Tags: grinder

I set up The Grinder and started the console:

```
 $ java net.grinder.Console
2013-02-21 16:23:29,718 INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-7.6.1.v20120215
2013-02-21 16:23:29,775 INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@:6373
```

then I started an agent which claims to be connected to the console:

```
 $ java net.grinder.Grinder
2013-02-21 16:23:38,488 INFO  agent: The Grinder 3.11
2013-02-21 16:23:38,557 INFO  agent: connected to console at localhost/127.0.0.1:6372
2013-02-21 16:23:38,557 INFO  agent: waiting for console signal
```

When I look in the console, I don't see any agents/processes. The above scenario remains the same whether I spec the hostname in the console and the grinder.properties file or not. Even without it spec'd in the props file the agent thinks it's connected but the console doesn't "see" it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to run them on the same host?

Comment: Any chance the versions of The Grinder you are running for the console and the agent are different?  If no, and you get no response here on StackOverflow, you could repost this question to the Grinder-use mailing list.

Comment: Nope, they are the same. But a coworker pointed me to this getting started guide ( http://blog.karit.geek.nz/2009/08/missing-grinder-3-getting-started-guide.html ), and following it I was able to get things working. When I get a sec I will figure out what is different and post here for future reference.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was? I am seeing the same problem, and am a bit lost.

Comment: Same here. Did anyone has an answer and willing to shere?